# Why didn't Lord Krishna help Draupadi when she asks if he can bring her sons back to life?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, pandavas

After the Kurukshetra war, Ashwatthama attacked the Pandavas' tent and killed their five sons. Ashwatthama had actually wanted to take revenge and kill the *Pandavas* but by mistake he killed their sons.

Draupadi asked Lord Krishna if he can bring her sons back to life but he refused to do so. However, Lord Krishna brought back his 6 brothers (sons of Devaki) who were killed by Kansa earlier. Why he didn't help Draupadi but did help Mata Devaki?